# How to generate text file using sql query in python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, dataframe

I am running sql query but not able to get data in appropriate manner.
Can you please help me how to do this and save in text file?

Query:

```
"SELECT trim(CONCAT_WS('|',mtd.Master_Job_Name,Seq,Table_Name,Source_File_Name_Lnd,landingdfname,Target_Path,query,mtd.Execution_Sequence  )) from imedical_master_metadata mtd inner join imedical_master_metadata_query mtq on (mtd.Master_Job_Name=mtq.Master_Job_Name) where mtd.Is_Active='Y' order by mtd.Execution_Sequence"
```

code:

```
with db.cursor() as cur:
     query_meta1 = ("SELECT trim(CONCAT_WS('|',mtd.Master_Job_Name,Seq,Table_Name,Source_File_Name_Lnd,landingdfname,Target_Path,query,mtd.Execution_Sequence  )) from imedical_master_metadata mtd inner join imedical_master_metadata_query mtq on (mtd.Master_Job_Name=mtq.Master_Job_Name) where mtd.Is_Active='Y' order by mtd.Execution_Sequence")
     res1 = cur.execute(query_meta1)
     res1 = cur.fetchall()
```

Getting output:

```
[{u"trim(CONCAT_WS('|',mtd.Master_Job_Name,Seq,Table_Name,Source_File_Name_Lnd,landingdfname,Target_Path,query,mtd.Execution_Sequence  ))"": ""CATEGORY|1|ADDITIONAL_QUESTIONS|/medaff/eureka/RawLayer/AMPIL/ADDITIONAL_QUESTIONS/|vw_additional_questions|/medaff/eureka/Refined/CATEGORY/|SELECT (row_number() over(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) as category_id, cat.CTGRY, mdm.group_id as mdm_category_id, mdm.DESCRPTN, from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'EST5EDT') as im_insrt_dt FROM (SELECT distinct NVL(CTGRY,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_additional_questions UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CTGRY,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CAST(QUICKCDE_CATGRY AS VARCHAR(4000)),'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CATG_MIR,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT  NVL(CATG,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_mir_slctd_respn UNION SELECT DISTINCT CTGRY FROM vw_call_dscssn UNION SELECT DISTINCT  vw_prod_strtgy.NM FROM vw_mdcl_dsscn INNER JOIN vw_prod_strtgy ON vw_mdcl_dsscn.PROD_STRTGY_VOD = vw_prod_strtgy.ID UNION SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_NAME AS CTGRY FROM vw_mdm_group where group_type = 'CATEGORY' ) cat LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME AS CATEGORY, GROUP_DESCRIPTION AS DESCRPTN FROM vw_mdm_group where group_type = 'CATEGORY') mdm ON cat.CTGRY = mdm.category|5""}","{u""trim(CONCAT_WS('|',mtd.Master_Job_Name,Seq,Table_Name,Source_File_Name_Lnd,landingdfname,Target_Path,query,mtd.Execution_Sequence  ))"": ""CATEGORY|2|CASE|/medaff/eureka/RawLayer/AMPIL/CASE/|vw_case|/medaff/eureka/Refined/CATEGORY/|SELECT (row_number() over(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) as category_id, cat.CTGRY, mdm.group_id as mdm_category_id, mdm.DESCRPTN, from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'EST5EDT') as im_insrt_dt FROM (SELECT distinct NVL(CTGRY,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_additional_questions UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CTGRY,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CAST(QUICKCDE_CATGRY AS VARCHAR(4000)),'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CATG_MIR,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT  NVL(CATG,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_mir_slctd_respn UNION SELECT DISTINCT CTGRY FROM vw_call_dscssn UNION SELECT DISTINCT  vw_prod_strtgy.NM FROM vw_mdcl_dsscn INNER JOIN vw_prod_strtgy ON vw_mdcl_dsscn.PROD_STRTGY_VOD = vw_prod_strtgy.ID UNION SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_NAME AS CTGRY FROM vw_mdm_group where group_type = 'CATEGORY' ) cat LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME AS CATEGORY, GROUP_DESCRIPTION AS DESCRPTN FROM vw_mdm_group where group_type = 'CATEGORY') mdm ON cat.CTGRY = mdm.category|5'}]
```

desired output:

```
CATEGORY|1|ADDITIONAL_QUESTIONS|/medaff/eureka/RawLayer/AMPIL/ADDITIONAL_QUESTIONS/|vw_additional_questions|/medaff/eureka/Refined/CATEGORY/|SELECT (row_number() over(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) as category_id, cat.CTGRY, mdm.group_id as mdm_category_id, mdm.DESCRPTN, from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'EST5EDT') as im_insrt_dt FROM (SELECT distinct NVL(CTGRY,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_additional_questions UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CTGRY,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CAST(QUICKCDE_CATGRY AS VARCHAR(4000)),'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CATG_MIR,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT  NVL(CATG,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_mir_slctd_respn UNION SELECT DISTINCT CTGRY FROM vw_call_dscssn UNION SELECT DISTINCT  vw_prod_strtgy.NM FROM vw_mdcl_dsscn INNER JOIN vw_prod_strtgy ON vw_mdcl_dsscn.PROD_STRTGY_VOD = vw_prod_strtgy.ID UNION SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_NAME AS CTGRY FROM vw_mdm_group where group_type = 'CATEGORY' ) cat LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME AS CATEGORY, GROUP_DESCRIPTION AS DESCRPTN FROM vw_mdm_group where group_type = 'CATEGORY') mdm ON cat.CTGRY = mdm.category|5

CATEGORY|2|CASE|/medaff/eureka/RawLayer/AMPIL/CASE/|vw_case|/medaff/eureka/Refined/CATEGORY/|SELECT (row_number() over(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) as category_id, cat.CTGRY, mdm.group_id as mdm_category_id, mdm.DESCRPTN, from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'EST5EDT') as im_insrt_dt FROM (SELECT distinct NVL(CTGRY,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_additional_questions UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CTGRY,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CAST(QUICKCDE_CATGRY AS VARCHAR(4000)),'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CATG_MIR,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT  NVL(CATG,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_mir_slctd_respn UNION SELECT DISTINCT CTGRY FROM vw_call_dscssn UNION SELECT DISTINCT  vw_prod_strtgy.NM FROM vw_mdcl_dsscn INNER JOIN vw_prod_strtgy ON vw_mdcl_dsscn.PROD_STRTGY_VOD = vw_prod_strtgy.ID UNION SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_NAME AS CTGRY FROM vw_mdm_group where group_type = 'CATEGORY' ) cat LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME AS CATEGORY, GROUP_DESCRIPTION AS DESCRPTN FROM vw_mdm_group where group_type = 'CATEGORY') mdm ON cat.CTGRY = mdm.category|5
```

Can you please help how to do this and save this in txt file?

Comment: The getting output portion is wrong. Please update it as per the output.

Comment: The quotes are not matching in python

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav, it is correct.

Comment: If I paste the getting output portion in python and assign it to any variable. It is showing error. The opening and closing quotes are not proper.

Comment: Still its facing issue. I will update it

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav, the output is coming like this: list[dict[list]]]

Comment: Please check out the solution. It will 100% work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer what you wanted. Run this code, you will get the desired ouput:

```
d = [{u"trim(CONCAT_WS('|',mtd.Master_Job_Name,Seq,Table_Name,Source_File_Name_Lnd,landingdfname,Target_Path,query,mtd.Execution_Sequence  ))": "CATEGORY|1|ADDITIONAL_QUESTIONS|/medaff/eureka/RawLayer/AMPIL/ADDITIONAL_QUESTIONS/|vw_additional_questions|/medaff/eureka/Refined/CATEGORY/|SELECT (row_number() over(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) as category_id, cat.CTGRY, mdm.group_id as mdm_category_id, mdm.DESCRPTN, from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'EST5EDT') as im_insrt_dt FROM (SELECT distinct NVL(CTGRY,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_additional_questions UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CTGRY,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CAST(QUICKCDE_CATGRY AS VARCHAR(4000)),'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CATG_MIR,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT  NVL(CATG,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_mir_slctd_respn UNION SELECT DISTINCT CTGRY FROM vw_call_dscssn UNION SELECT DISTINCT  vw_prod_strtgy.NM FROM vw_mdcl_dsscn INNER JOIN vw_prod_strtgy ON vw_mdcl_dsscn.PROD_STRTGY_VOD = vw_prod_strtgy.ID UNION SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_NAME AS CTGRY FROM vw_mdm_group where group_type = 'CATEGORY' ) cat LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME AS CATEGORY, GROUP_DESCRIPTION AS DESCRPTN FROM vw_mdm_group where group_type = 'CATEGORY') mdm ON cat.CTGRY = mdm.category|5"},{u"trim(CONCAT_WS('|',mtd.Master_Job_Name,Seq,Table_Name,Source_File_Name_Lnd,landingdfname,Target_Path,query,mtd.Execution_Sequence  ))": "CATEGORY|2|CASE|/medaff/eureka/RawLayer/AMPIL/CASE/|vw_case|/medaff/eureka/Refined/CATEGORY/|SELECT (row_number() over(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) as category_id, cat.CTGRY, mdm.group_id as mdm_category_id, mdm.DESCRPTN, from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'EST5EDT') as im_insrt_dt FROM (SELECT distinct NVL(CTGRY,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_additional_questions UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CTGRY,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CAST(QUICKCDE_CATGRY AS VARCHAR(4000)),'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT NVL(CATG_MIR,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_case UNION SELECT DISTINCT  NVL(CATG,'Unspecified') CTGRY FROM vw_mir_slctd_respn UNION SELECT DISTINCT CTGRY FROM vw_call_dscssn UNION SELECT DISTINCT  vw_prod_strtgy.NM FROM vw_mdcl_dsscn INNER JOIN vw_prod_strtgy ON vw_mdcl_dsscn.PROD_STRTGY_VOD = vw_prod_strtgy.ID UNION SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_NAME AS CTGRY FROM vw_mdm_group where group_type = 'CATEGORY' ) cat LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME AS CATEGORY, GROUP_DESCRIPTION AS DESCRPTN FROM vw_mdm_group where group_type = 'CATEGORY') mdm ON cat.CTGRY = mdm.category|5"}]
with open("output.txt", 'w') as file:
    for i in d:
        for j in i.values():
            print(j)
            file.writelines(j + "\n")
```

Comment: Hi Vaibhav.. Thank you for the great help. I am getting the data .

Comment: Can you please help me for one more time? Actually i have to add two text file. In First file header is present and in 2nd file data is present. I need to add them and make a single file.

Comment: Is this posted as different thread or I should answer it here?

Comment: @jay Can you tell me if you have posted the question or should I answer here?

Comment: I have done that part Vaibhav.. Thank you for your great help.

Comment: Welcome :-)....

Answer (score 0):

I think the output error is due to query string you us on cursor.
Build *query_meta* vairable as string (i.e. without bracket), e.g. :

> query_meta = "SELECT ..."

This will solve the result obtained from fetchall.

If you want to save the output you can convert it into pandas dataframe and then use pandas write function.
This below is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

with db.cursor() as cur:
 query_meta1 = "SELECT ..."
 cur.execute(query_meta1)
 result = cur.fetchall()
 df = pd.Dataframe(result)
 df.to_csv("test.csv")
```